# Random white flash in phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app I made with Phonegap and Jquery Mobile that goes between multiple multipage Jquery Mobile documents. Its works well for what I need but a strange thing that happens is occasionally I get a white flash when going in between the different html files. Now I've seen that this is a common issue when using JQM and Phonegap but from all the other post I've looked at but from other than getting rid of the page transitions, are there any other solutions? Has this problem been resolved in Phonegap 2.5? 


Im using Jquery Mobile 1.3, Jquery 1.9, and Phonegap 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some good documentation for this [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

I had a similar issue recently, you can either set the page transition to 'none':

`<a href="" data-transition="none">XX</a>`

This alleviated all issues of flicker for me.

You could also try adding this:

`.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }`

To your CSS, it's not a perfect fix however, and caused severe instability for me.

Comment: yeah the changing the transitions to none helped a little but it just happens randomly. I will go from one page to another and not have the flicker, and then a moment or two later when I go back, I'll get it. Cant tell if its a jquery problem or phonegap